# Refrence two different classes wich are on one level in SCSS

Tags: html, sass, typo3

I have an accordeon in which is build like this:

```
    <div class="panel">
       <div class="panel-heading"></div>
       <div class="panel-content collapse/collpase in" aria-expanded="false" ></div>
   </div>
```

CSS build like this:

```
.panel{
       .panel-heading{}
       .panel-content{}
}
```

**QUESTION:**

when `panel-content` is collpase/collapse in i need to change my css in the `panel-heading` .

Is it even possible when they are on the same level?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to target elements coming **after**, at the same depth level, but not **before**. With this HTML (switched elements):

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-content collapse/collpase in" aria-expanded="false" ></div>
    <div class="panel-heading"></div>  
</div>
```

You could have done this:

```
.panel {
    .panel-heading {}
    .panel-content {
        &.collapse.in + .panel-heading {
            // Changes here
        }
    }
}
```

A better way to do it (IMO) would be to use your `collapse` class on the container:

```
<div class="panel collapsed">
    <div class="panel-heading"></div> 
    <div class="panel-content"></div> 
</div>
```

And the Sass:

```
.panel {
    .panel-heading {}
    .panel-content {}
    &.collapsed {
        .panel-heading {
            // Changes here
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm perfectly aware this is not always possible, due to framework restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but not in the way you HTML is structured right now. You can target siblings like so:

```
.bother + .sister {
  color: red;
}
```

This will result in any `.sister` elements right next to `.brother` elements to have red text. You can also use `~` instead of `+` so it's not a close sibling, but instead one that's simply further down the tree, but still a sibling. The problem is, this only works one way. So there's no way for the `.panel-content` to look back and see if the siblings above it match the selector.